# Prove that $ \tan 20°\cdot \tan 40° \cdot \tan 60° \cdot \tan 80° = 3$

Tags: trigonometry

We have to prove that  $$ \tan  20°\cdot  \tan  40° \cdot  \tan  60° \cdot  \tan  80° = 3$$

I tried to use the formula

$$\displaystyle\frac {\tan a+\tan b}{1-\tan a\cdot \tan b}$$

But in that I got stuck .

Comment: Closely related: [How can I find the following product? $ \tan 20^\circ \cdot \tan 40^\circ \cdot \tan 80^\circ.$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805821/how-can-i-find-the-following-product-tan-20-circ-cdot-tan-40-circ-cdot).

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455070/proving-a-fact-tan6-circ-tan42-circ-tan12-circ-tan24-cir

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Hint:

$$\tan\alpha\tan(60^{\circ}-\alpha)\tan(60^{\circ}+\alpha)=\tan3\alpha$$
If $\alpha=20^{\circ}$, then
$$\tan20^{\circ}\tan40^{\circ}\tan80^{\circ}=\tan60^{\circ}=\sqrt3$$

Comment: yeah , correct hint