# Eccentricity of conic given by a complicated equation with trigonometric coefficients such as $\tan 10^\circ$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

> Find the eccentricity of the conic given by:
>
> $$\left(x\tan 10^\circ+y\tan 20^\circ+\tan 30^\circ\right)\left(x\tan 120^\circ+y\tan 220^\circ+\tan 320^\circ\right)+2018=0$$

What I have tried

$$\bigg(x\tan10^\circ+y\tan 20^\circ+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\bigg)\bigg(\sqrt{3}\; x +y\tan 220^\circ+\tan 320^\circ\bigg)+2018=0$$

$$\begin{align}\Longrightarrow\quad 
&\sqrt{3}x^2+\sqrt{3}xy\tan 20^\circ+x+xy\tan 10^\circ\tan 220^\circ+y^2\tan 20^\circ\tan 220^\circ \\[4pt]
&+\frac{y}{\sqrt{3}}\tan 220^\circ+x\tan 10^\circ\tan 220^\circ+y\tan 20^\circ\tan 320^\circ+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\tan 320^\circ \\[4pt]
&+2018=0
\end{align}$$

How do I solve it? Help me, please.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentricity_(mathematics)#Values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Equating to $0$ the expressions inside the parentheses we get the equations of two lines, which are the asymptotes of the hyperbola:
$$
x\tan 10°+y\tan 20°+\tan 30°=0,\quad
-x\tan 60°+y\tan 40°+\tan 320°=0,
$$
where I used $\tan120°=-\tan60°$ and $\tan220°=\tan40°$.

But these lines are perpendicular, because
$$\tan10°\tan60°=\tan20°\tan40°$$
(you can check that with a calculator, or read the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172182/proving-tan20-circ-cdot-tan30-circ-cdot-tan40-circ-tan10), remembering that $\tan60°=1/\tan30°$).

Hence this is a rectangular hyperbola and its eccentricity is $\sqrt2$.